# Spatie media library upload to Amazon s3 bucket subfolder

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am using spatie media library in Laravel with the below code to upload images to s3 bucket

```
$file = $this->fileUploadModel
             ->addMediaFromDisk($file->path(), 's3')
             ->toMediaCollection();
```

The image is saved to s3 bucket on the format:

- my_bucket_name/1/image_name.png
- my_bucket_name/2/image_name.png
  etc

However I want a way to store the images inside an **images** folder ie.

my_bucket_name/**images**/1/image_name.png

By using only Laravel you can do that with a simple:

```
$file->store('images','s3');
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the following solution:

Un file config/filesystems.php I defined the following disk:

```
's3-media' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'root' => 'images/media',
    ],
```

In position ***root*** of the ***s3-media*** array I indicate the main path where the images will be stored.